# DF is made of string values need to grep/regex string and calculate

Tags: python, pandas

I have cleaned up a DF that have multiple columns and ~3000 rows. One column has a sting with various text and delimiters. I need to perform a calculation on values in the string.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| abc: 208V, 60A, Three phase, abcd | 1 |
| KW: | 600 |

In row 1 I would need to calculate KW by grep/regex-ing the values. (P = V * A). After this is done, I would like to run additional reports/analyses with Pandas, numpy and matplotlib

What is the best approach to this. My understanding that iterating on a DF is not the best solution? Should I dump this a file iterate over the data an re-import to a new DF?

Cheers!

New and ignorant, need advice. :-)

Comment: Can you provide a few more rows to see how the DataFrame generalizes?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a pattern of `[volts]V, [amps]A` on every row in column A, we can use `df.str.extract` with the relevant regex pattern, convert the resulting table to float and then take the product across the columns.

```
df['P'] = df["Column A"].str.extract("(?P<V>\d+)V, (?P<A>\d+)A").astype("float").product(axis=1, skipna = False)
```